# Using gcc for C in Rmarkdown

Tags: c, gcc, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to run C code in Rmarkdown with gcc. When I try to run the following chunk:

```c
{R engine='c' engine.path='/usr/bin/gcc'}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n"); // say hello world
}
```

I get the following error: `Error: unexpected symbol in "int main"`. My `gcc` executable has the correct path, and I've also tried `/usr/bin/clang`. I am using Rstudio on an 11" MacBook Air.

Comment: maybe `//` comments are not accepted. Have you tried `/* comment */` or removing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is it you *really* want to do?  Rmarkdown cannot build *executables* with a `main()` for you, but it has had Rcpp integrations for a long time.

The following "just works":

````
---
title: "RMarkdown Demo"
author: "Dirk"
date: "November 25, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## C++ Code

```{r engine='Rcpp'}
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return(x);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}
```

## Deployed

```{r}
fibonacci(10L)
fibonacci(20L)
```
````

and creates what I include below.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to just have a standalone C code chunk that I can run just like an R or Python code chunk? I've known about Rcpp but it seems that its main use is to use faster C++ functions in R.